# How good is it, "decent"?

Tags: word-usage, connotations

When you say "a **decent** meal" or "a **decent** job", how good is it usually, on a scale of one to ten? 5 or 6? or 8? or above that?

Comment: I find this a good question because the real problem to understand here is not the use of the word "decent" but the use of the word "good" which is inherently linked with the word decent in a two dimensional respect. As both a quantity and as an indicator of morality (social awareness).

Comment: How considerate and thoughtful you are! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From what I know, decent is slightly behind "okay" as in "you did okay" which, for some people is borderline acceptable (as in 5/6).

I'd say decent is somewhere around 4, where it is still acceptable but not to the extent of which people would say it is commendable (despite the fact that saying "decent" anyway is a sort of commendation, but let's be honest, you won't be saying that if you are impressed, would you?)

Comment: British people are often given to understatement (or, as we see it, lack of hyperbole) and will say 'decent' where more effusive peoples might gush enthusiastically and say 'great' or 'wonderful'. Also as a personal attribute, to call someone a 'decent' person means that they are honest, fair, considerate, unselfish, etc, and is high praise. In many situations 'decent' is binary, rather than a scale - someone is either decent or they are not. No decent man would hit a woman.

Comment: Your answer is so clear to me. Thank you Mr. or Ms. obi. And to Mr. Michael Harvey, thank you for your detailed answer, too. You mean that "decent" usually means "pretty good", right?

Comment: I do believe that I am in the wrong with my attempted answer, and your answer has given quite a new insight on how vague and vast the language truly is haha, thank you, nevertheless, for the correction and addition.

Answer (score -2):

This is not an easy question as the word decent has several meanings

My answer is the word **decent  is usually used not only to "*quantify*" the value of something but simultaneously used to "*rate it in a social and/or moral aspect*"**

**Lets use Junk food as an example**. In most peoples mind this does not rate as a decent meal

Someone may find a large Burger meal deal as a decent choice for lunch as it is relatively cheap and filling so it would fit the definition of

**decent; adjective acceptable, satisfactory, or reasonable:**

whilst someone else will find a Burger meal as a not acceptable alternative for a lunch. Why? because they believe that it is "junk food" and therefore not good. They maybe "health Junkie's" or vegan's  and within their social circle, the eating of a fried meat Pattie is not socially acceptable. Therefore does not fit with the definition

**decent: adjective, socially acceptable or good:**

In the compromise of general society the burger maybe an acceptable lunch but would rarely be described as a decent meal. OK, maybe in some peoples mind that is an extreme example, but I used that as an example that it is not so easy to universally place a mathematical quantity on some words.

**Working for the "Mob"** maybe quite rewarding and have a good remunerative package but it **would not be described as a decent job**.

Comment: You're saying it depends but from what you said I can infer that "decent" means "6 or so" on a scale of 1 to 10, right? Thank you for your detailed answer:)